Event hub No such host is known
I subscribed to an event hub in order to fetch messages from there
code:
            BlobContainerClient storageClient = new BlobContainerClient(new Uri(serviceConfig.BlobContainerName), certificate);

            var processor = new EventProcessorClient
            (
                storageClient,
                EventHubConsumerClient.DefaultConsumerGroupName,
                eventHubNamespace,
                eventHubName,
                certificate
            );
            
            processor.ProcessEventAsync += ProcessEventHandler;
            processor.ProcessErrorAsync += ProcessErrorHandler;

            await processor.StartProcessingAsync();

eventArgs.Exception.Message: No such host is known
eventArgs.Operation: Retrieving list of partition identifiers from a Consumer Client.
Stack trace:
[EventHubListener] error StackTrace    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Transport.AmqpTransportInitiator.<>c.<ConnectAsync>b__17_1(IAsyncResult r)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpConnectionScope.<CreateAndOpenConnectionAsync>d__80.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.FaultTolerantAmqpObject`1.<OnCreateAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1.<GetOrCreateAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1.<GetOrCreateAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpConnectionScope.<OpenManagementLinkAsync>d__76.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.FaultTolerantAmqpObject`1.<OnCreateAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1.<GetOrCreateAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1.<GetOrCreateAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpClient.<GetPropertiesAsync>d__30.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpClient.<GetPropertiesAsync>d__30.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.EventHubConnection.<GetPropertiesAsync>d__37.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.EventHubConnection.<GetPartitionIdsAsync>d__38.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Primitives.EventProcessor`1.<ListPartitionIdsAsync>d__83.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Primitives.EventProcessor`1.<RunProcessingAsync>d__87.MoveNext()

From the machine where i deployed the code i tried this:
.\psping.exe -n 25 -i 1 -q .servicebus.windows.net:5671 -nobanner
answer
The EventHub is authenticated through a Service Principal which has EventHub Owner/Reader/Writer roles assigned.

Check your eventHubNamespace parameter.  The error indicates that your host's networking stack was unable to resolve the hostname when attempting to create a connection.   Most often, this is due to the FQNS being malformed.

Also - what package version are you using, because there's a validation check that runs when you call StartProcessing which would fail if no connection could be established.   Unsure if you're running a really old build or if you've got intermittent network problems..

Is your issue resolved? Please follow the steps of Jesse Squire

Hi Jesse! Those are the packages:  

I was using the same namespace in the ping command also in the code
